# Azure Authentication MSAL 1.3 - Angular SPA - After login, the application keeps loading forever and doesn't stop

Tags: angular, azure, authentication, single-page-application, msal.js

Lately, I deployed an Angular9 SPA on Azure and using MSAL1.3 by following [Azure official docs for MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=angular). Then once I login, the home screens keeps on loading forever, sometimes it shows error msg and sometimes no error but keeps loading. Point to note is this doesn't happen all the time. Very few times it loads homepage and stops, occasionally it loads 4-6 times and stops.

I tried to find a fix for this, or atleast a clue on what could be the issue with no luck. Can somebody help me on this or guide me on how could I solve the issue? Note: I followed same as mentioned in the docs from above.

Below is the code from my `app.component.ts`

```
this.broadcastSub = this.broadcastService.subscribe("msal:loginFailure", payload => {
      console.log('login failure', payload);
    });

    this.broadcastSub = this.broadcastService.subscribe("msal:loginSuccess", payload => {
      console.log('login success', payload);
    });

    this.broadcastSub = this.broadcastService.subscribe("msal:acquireTokenSuccess", payload => {
      console.log('token success', payload);
      this.authService.authorizeUser({
        username: payload.account.name,
        email: payload.account.userName.toLowerCase()
      });
    });

    this.broadcastSub = this.broadcastService.subscribe("msal:acquireTokenFailure", payload => {
      console.log('token fail', payload);
    });
```

The above code runs immediately after login. I heard about `handleCallback()` but not sure how to implement (or is it a solution) with the confusing docs as a beginner.

Comment: Please share the error message

Comment: Are you still looking for any help with this question?